# Catkin Eclipse Integration (Type 'sensor_msgs::PointCloud2' could not be resolved)

Tags: pcl, catkin, sensor-msgs, ros-groovy, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use Eclipse with Catkin. I am having some problems with Index, for example, I have just tried to do this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials) and Eclipse does not recognizes the index to "sensor_msgs::PointCloud2" (all these type).

I am able to compile the package into Eclipse(CTRL+B), it is working fine, my problem is with the Eclipse indexer.

My steps to make Eclipse compile catkin projects were:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
$ catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j8
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ eclipse
```

File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace...

When I open the .cpp file, I got some errors:

```
Type 'sensor_msgs::PointCloud2' could not be resolved
Type 'sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr' could not be resolved
            ...
```

But, how I said, I`m able to compile the package, I just have NOT the indexes for this type.

Can you guys help me to make Eclipse index this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69463/catkin-eclipse-integration-(type-%27sensor_msgs::pointcloud2%27-could-not-be-resolved)/) by [barcelosandre](https://answers.ros.org/users/4303/barcelosandre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2013-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've had this problem a lot (using rosbuild, not catkin) when the Eclipse C++ indexer ran out of memory while indexing and crashed, leaving a bad index behind. Increasing the memory available to the Java VM by adding `-vmargs -Xmx1500m` to the eclipse call helped.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1